# Script não funciona com host externo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Meu script não funciona com arquivos hospedados em host exetrno

Meus arquivos se encontram nesse host:

Como faço para que eles eja executado nesse script abaixo?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

var resizeOwnr = function(width, height)
{
    var  = $('');
    .css('width', width);
    .css('height', height);
}

$(function()
{
    function ()
    {
        var  = $('');
        if()
        {
            var flashvars = 
            {
                system : '',
                url : ''
            };
            var params = {};
            var attributes = {};

            params.allowscriptaccess = '';
            params.allowFullScreen = 'true';
            params.allowFullScreenInteractive = 'true';

            swfobject.embedSWF('', '', '640', '480', '11.2.0', '', flashvars, params, attributes);
        }
    }

    embed();
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para isso será necessário usar o google api,

da uma olhada na documentação:

https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/

O próprio exemplo do google:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Google Picker Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    // The Browser API key obtained from the Google Developers Console.
    // Replace with your own Browser API key, or your own key.
    var developerKey = 'xxxxxxxYYYYYYYY-12345678';

    // The Client ID obtained from the Google Developers Console. Replace with your own Client ID.
    var clientId = "1234567890-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.apps.googleusercontent.com"

    // Replace with your own App ID. (Its the first number in your Client ID)
    var appId = "1234567890";

    // Scope to use to access user's Drive items.
    var scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];

    var pickerApiLoaded = false;
    var oauthToken;

    // Use the Google API Loader script to load the google.picker script.
    function loadPicker() {
      gapi.load('auth', {'callback': onAuthApiLoad});
      gapi.load('picker', {'callback': onPickerApiLoad});
    }

    function onAuthApiLoad() {
      window.gapi.auth.authorize(
          {
            'client_id': clientId,
            'scope': scope,
            'immediate': false
          },
          handleAuthResult);
    }

    function onPickerApiLoad() {
      pickerApiLoaded = true;
      createPicker();
    }

    function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
      if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
        createPicker();
      }
    }

    // Create and render a Picker object for searching images.
    function createPicker() {
      if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
        var view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
        view.setMimeTypes("image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg");
        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
            .setAppId(appId)
            .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
            .addView(view)
            .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView())
            .setDeveloperKey(developerKey)
            .setCallback(pickerCallback)
            .build();
         picker.setVisible(true);
      }
    }

    // A simple callback implementation.
    function pickerCallback(data) {
      if (data.action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        var fileId = data.docs[0].id;
        alert('The user selected: ' + fileId);
      }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="result"></div>

    <!-- The Google API Loader script. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=loadPicker"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---------------------------EDIT-----------------------

Como não havia entendi a pergunta vou deixar a parte de cima para consultas futuras de outros usuários.

No seu caso cara, não é possivel dar load no script da forma que você quer, pois quando você fornece um caminho dinamico como você está fazendo:

```
" url : '/swf/Robotech_-_The_Macross_Saga.zip'"
```

O código via interpretar que existe uma pasta no mesmo nível da raiz do seu projeto ou do arquivo que está sendo executado dependendo da arquitetura que chama "swf" e nela contem o seu arquivo, mas como o seu servidor é externo, não tem forma dinâmica de chamar isso referenciando seu próprio código, entendeu?

Quando você passa o caminho dinâmico, a referencia é o seu arquivo que está sendo executado.

Comment: Acho que não foi entendida a pergunta, o host funciona se eu deixa o caminho completo dos arquivos no script,  acontece que eu queria usa metade do caminho como está no script

Comment: tá certo entendi mal. editei a resposta.

Comment: Não é possivel adiciona algum codigo extra fazendo que o script busque o inicio do caminho da pasta?

Comment: Não porque não é uma pasta "local" é um externo, você poderia deixar essa url salva em uma variavel e usar ela pra concatenar no ajax com o path, mas acho que ia dar na mesma, talvez só pra unificar e não precisar alterar em muitos lugares.

Comment: O objetivo seria se por a caso eu ter que troca de servidor não precisa edita os arquivos, apenas muda a pasta de servidor

Comment: então, só funcionaria se fosse tudo local. mas você pode deixar uma variavel com a parte que mudaria por exemplo var url = "www.seuhost.com.br"; dai vc usaria ela no seu codigo inteiro, dai se precisar mudar o server, vc só mudaria essa variavel e bum. existe N outras possibilidades, mas nenhuma do jeito q vc quer, teria q fazer algo similar.